# update table in mysql when user loses focus of a textarea?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I want users of my site to be able to update their profile information by clicking into a textarea. When they type in some text and click out of the text area (on blur), I want this to update a table in my database called 'bio'.

I have been working on this for several days, I'm ashamed to admit but I am really new to php and sql so I am learning as I go along. I have tried to make sense of a script but it's probably completely wrong. Can someone please advise me of what I need to do?

Here's my code:

```
 <textarea id="bio" style="width: 456px; 
    margin-top:3px;
    text-align:left;
    margin-left:-2px;
    height: 120px;
    resize: none; 
    border: hidden;" textarea name="bio" data-id="bio">
    <?php echo $profile['bio'] ?>
  </textarea>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    $('textarea').on('blur',function () {
        var bioVal = $(this).val(), 
            id = $(this).data('id');        

        $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "includes/changebio.php",
             data: {bio:bioVal , id:id},
             success: function(msg) {
                 $('#bio-' + id).val(msg);
             }
       })
    });

  </script>
```

Here's the url php file that should do the work:

```
function update_profilebio() {
            global $connection;
            global $profile_id;
            $query = "UPDATE ptb_profiles
                      SET bio=''
                        WHERE ptb_profiles.user_id = \"$profile_id\"
                        AND ptb_profiles.user_id = ptb_users.id";
            $update_profilebio_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            confirm_query($update_profilebio_set);
            return $update_profilebio_set;

            }
```

Comment: ptb_profiles is the database which contains the table 'bio' just to let anyone know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked HTML+JavaScript code and AJAX POST request is sending data correctly to the PHP script (You may check this in Chrome Developer Tools or with Firebug add-on).

This changebio.php script has only definition of this update_profilebio() function ? Definition alone won't execute this function, you need to call it.

```
<?php
    update_profilebio(); // tells php to call the function, defined below

    function update_profilebio() {
        global $connection;
        global $profile_id;
        $query = "UPDATE ptb_profiles
                  SET bio=''
                    WHERE ptb_profiles.user_id = \"$profile_id\"
                    AND ptb_profiles.user_id = ptb_users.id";
        $update_profilebio_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
        confirm_query($update_profilebio_set);
        return $update_profilebio_set;
    } 
?>
```

Also, SQL query has two conditions and I don't understand this part "...AND ptb_profiles.user_id = ptb_users.id ". You update only one column in one table, the only thing you need is user id which you provide in first where condition.

Comment: Absolutely, the AND ptb_profiles.user_id = ptb_users.id statement doesn't make sense

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML + jQuery code looks ok, just cheng php output `<?php echo $profile['bio'] ?>` by adding `htmlspecialchars`, that will help you avoid some trouble

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($profile['bio']); ?>
```

The thing that fails in your code is SQL query; you are setting bio to empty text. Also  you have condition on matching `user_id` with other table id, but you have not joined this table in your query. Just requiring `user_id` to be equal to given integer is enough. Also remember to escape user input properly, to prevent them from injecting malicious code into your database.

SQL should look like this:

```
$bio = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bio']);

$query = "
UPDATE 
   ptb_profiles 
SET 
   bio='{$bio}'
WHERE
   ptb_profiles.user_id = " . intval($profile_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You got your quoting wrong, try something like this

```
 $query = "UPDATE ptb_profiles SET bio='".$_REQUEST['bio']."'
           WHERE ptb_profiles.user_id = ".$profile_id;
```

SQL usually uses single quotes, PHP uses both.

Comment: thanks guys for all your suggestions, i've tried both of those in my changebio.php file and the textarea still doesnt update so am guessing it's a problem therefore with the javacript/ajax?